# SASS files conversion in blogdown (sam theme)

Tags: css, r, sass, blogdown

I am trying to build a website using blogdown, and the Hugo theme [Sam](https://github.com/victoriadrake/hugo-theme-sam).

This theme has SASS files that get converted into a minified css file.
When I change something in the SASS file, like for example the background color, it is not taken into account when using `serve_site`.

Is there a way to make this work using `blogdown`?

A way to reproduce the issue is:

- Create an empty directory called for ex. test_sam, and set it as a working directory
- then do:

```
   library(blogdown)
   new_site(theme = "victoriadrake/hugo-theme-sam")
```

- Try to change something in `test_sam/themes/hugo-theme-sam/assets/sass/style.sass`, for example:

change

```
html
    background-color: $dark-grey
```

to

```
html
    background-color: $white
```

This doesn't produce any change.
Color variables (such as `$white`) are defined in `test_sam/themes/hugo-theme-sam/assets/sass/_vars.sass`
The odd thing is that if I change it to an undefined variable name like `$yellow`, I get the following error message:

> Building sites … ERROR 2019/12/27 20:44:39 Transformation failed: SCSS
>   processing failed: file "stdin", line 11, col 23: Undefined variable:
>   "$yellow".  Total in 197 ms Error: Error building site: logged 1
>   error(s)

which shows that blogdown does access the sass files to build the site.

I have very little knowledge about website building nor css, so maybe there is something quite obvious that I'm not getting.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sass has to be compiled to traditional CSS; I'm not sure if blogdown does that when it builds the site

Comment: I don't think it does. The two files in public/css/ remain unchanged after modifying the sass files. I'm not sure if there is a way to get this to work using blogdown.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but I found [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/319) that seems related. I made the change to the SCSS that you mentioned, ran `build_site`, then called `hugo server -D` in the terminal and got a version with the background changed to white. So the issue might be just in it not being updated in RStudio.

Comment: @camille Thanks for the link, that's very useful! It works for me as well serving the site from the command line. I'll see if I can use the info in the issue to make it work using serve_site().

Answer (score 0):

Although late to answer, I solved this issue with the same theme by setting the "blogdown.generator.server"  option to TRUE.

```
options("blogdown.generator.server" = TRUE)
blogdown::serve_site()
```

Update: This actually seems to be a common issue with the Sam theme specifically. The theme uses some tools not included with Hugo, and you have to download them separately. It's [addressed in the README](https://github.com/victoriadrake/hugo-theme-sam#requirements).

Open Terminal and run:

```
npm install -g postcss-cli
npm install -g autoprefixer
```

After that, blogdown::serve_site() worked normally for me. It also fixed some plot rendering issues I was having.